# Primefaces exporting only one expandable table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am trying to export a view to xlsx using PrimeFaces extensions. I have a main table and an expandable row with 2 tables inside.

The exporter works fine for the first dataTable in the expandable row, but not for the other one. Any ideas?

```
<p:dataTable id="mainTable" var="mainObject" value="#{mainBean.mainList}">
    <p:column exportable="false" width="5%">  
        <p:rowToggler />  
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="main column A"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{mainObject.columnA}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="main column B"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{mainObject.columnB}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:rowExpansion>

        <p:datTable id="relatedTableA" var="relatedA" value="#{mainObject.relatedA}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Related A"/>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Related A column A"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{relatedA.columnA}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Related A column B"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{relatedA.columnB}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:datTable id="relatedTableB" var="relatedB" value="#{mainObject.relatedB}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Related B"/>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Related B column A"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{relatedB.columnA}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Related B column B"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{relatedB.columnB}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </p:rowExpansion>

</p:dataTable>

<h:commandLink>
   <p:graphicImage url="/resources/images/Excel32.png" width="32"/>
   <pe:exporter type="xlsx" target="mainTable" fileName="fileExport" facetBackground="#AAFFBB" datasetPadding="4" />   
</h:commandLink>
```

I followed this guide: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/expandableTable.jsf

In my app, the view works perfect. I use the toggle and then it shows the 2 tables. The only problem is that it exports only one of the expandables.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemes this is simply not supported.

In the exporter component source code when it comes to [exporting the row expensions](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/eaf2d477e93b5b024d94a3ac5e43cadb52d10d52/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/exporter/ExcelExporter.java#L767) they have hard coded to consider the first child for each rowExpansion only:

```
if (rowExpansion.getChildren().get(0) instanceof DataTable) {
    final DataTable childTable = (DataTable) rowExpansion.getChildren().get(0);
    // ...
}
```

This is why you only get the first sub table in your output.

Using the [customExporter feature](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf) you have the chance to extend the `ExcelExporter` and override the method `exportCells` which seemes responsible for your problem. Then change the behavior to do a loop on `rowExpansion.getChildren()` instead of just getting the first element.

General steps to configure a custom exporter from [the linked site](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf):

> Step 1: Create a folder named META-INF under resouces folder.Below
>   META-INF folder create another folder called services.
>
> Step 2: Creae a
>   file with the name "ExporterFactory" as a service(Fully binary name of
>   the service).
>       Here it should be org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.ExporterFactory.
>
> Step 3:
>   Provide your own implementaions/providers of Exporter factory anywhere
>   in your project.
>       And copy the absolute path of custom exporter factory implementation in the ExporterFactory file
>       How to do : Copy the file content of DefaultExporterFactory and rename the file as CustomExporterFactory.Copy the absolute path
>   org.primefaces.extensions.showcase.util.CustomExporterFactory in
>   ExporterFactory file.
>
> Step 4: Copy the exporter implementations and
>   add your own changes.And call these custom     implementations(Ex
>   PDFCustomExporter,ExcelCustomExporter) instead built-in
>   implmentations(Ex PDFExporter,ExcelExporter)

Comment: I thought I would have to use the custom exporter feature, but you know.. high hopes..

Thank you for the quickly reply.